# Jetty 9.0 embedded and RestEasy 3.0 keeps throwing NoSuchMethodError

Tags: jetty, jax-rs, resteasy, embedded-jetty, nosuchmethoderror

Today I had the idea to build a very simple web application, which would be powered by a REST backend. Since I wanted a very lightweight server I started looking at Jetty. And since I wanted to try another JAX-RS implementation than Jersey I looked at RestEasy. I thought those 2 would be easy to implement. I was wrong...

I imported the basic Jetty server and servlet dependencies since I thought that were the only server requirements for a basic (REST only) Jetty server (I alto tried to use the webapp dependency; this gave the same errors).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.0.RC0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.0.RC0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-servlets</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.0.RC0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then I imported the basic RestEasy dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1.Final</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1.Final</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>async-http-servlet-3.0</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1.Final</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Main method:

```
public class ExampleActivator {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Server server = new Server(8080);
        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.NO_SESSIONS);
        context.setContextPath("/");
        ServletHolder h = new ServletHolder(new HttpServlet30Dispatcher());
        h.setInitParameter("javax.ws.rs.Application", "packages.ExampleResources");
        context.addServlet(h, "/*");
        server.setHandler(context);
        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```

ExampleResources:

```
public class ExampleResources extends Application {

    private static final ImmutableSet services = ImmutableSet.of(
            ExampleResourceImpl.class
    );

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return services;
    }
}
```

ExampleResourceImpl:

```
@Path("activities")
public class ExampleResourceImpl {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getAll() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

When I go to the webapge I get the following trace:

```
250 [main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - jetty-9.0.0.RC0
911 [main] INFO org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment - Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class packages.ExampleResources
939 [main] INFO org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment - Adding class resource packages.ExampleResourceImpl from Application class packages.ExampleResources
1005 [main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler - started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@702ab48{/,null,AVAILABLE}
1037 [main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector - Started ServerConnector@465ed596{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
6315 [qtp84346444-13] WARN org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler - Error for /activities
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.BuiltResponse.getHeaders()Ljavax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedMap;
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.setDefaultContentType(ServerResponseWriter.java:195)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.writeNomapResponse(ServerResponseWriter.java:46)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:411)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:376)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:179)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:448)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1070)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1004)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.run(HttpChannel.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.run(AbstractConnection.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:520)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Normally this would mean that I forgot a dependency, however I really have no clue what's going on.

Comment: jetty 9.0.4.v20130625 should be used in lieu of an RC

Comment: I've changed the Jetty dependencies to version 9.0.4.v2013062. I keep getting the same exception.

Comment: just run into the same problem.. in my case starting jetty with `mvn run-exploded` works fine, and with `mvn run` it doesnt!? adding jaxrs-api did fix it..

Comment: @Wouter Your question helped me to build REST service without Web.xml. You should write a blog because there isn't any as clear and simple as yours.

Answer (score 7):

I just stumbled upon the same issue. The solution was to add the jaxrs-api explicitly as the first dependency in the list of dependencies.

```
<dependencies>
  <!-- jaxrs-api is the very first dependency -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4.Final</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- here come the other depdendencies -->
</dependencies>
```

Jackson uses the jsr311-api that provides the same `Response` class that is used by the `BuiltResponse` class. Unfortunately, this `Response` does not contain the `getHeaders()` method. So even though the dependency is resolved, it is using a wrong class. If somehow the Jackson dependency gets before the Resteasy one, then the exception above will be raised.

Comment: I just excluded the jsr311-api and it's working now.

Comment: This answer worked for me, but "first dependency" really meant "first dependency"--my problem was that both Swagger and JBoss were loading the conflicting dependency, and until I listed this dep before JBoss, my tests would not pass. In the end, `<exclusions>` were unnecessary, and did not work on their own.

Answer (score 2):

I had the very same problem. First of all it was working using JAX-RS 2 and then it was migrated to JAX-RS 3, so I thought it had something to do with that. After failing in trying to get JBoss use JAX-RS 3 from app via Maven and jboss-deployment-structure.xml, I tried upgrading JBoss modules, which can be done using the following procedure:

> 3.1. Upgrading Resteasy Within JBoss AS 7
>   Resteasy is bundled with JBoss AS 7. You will likely have the need to upgrade Resteasy in AS7.
>   The Resteasy distribution comes with a zip file called resteasy-jboss-modules-3.0.1.Final.zip.
>   Unzip this file while with the modules/ directory of the JBoss AS7 distribution. This will overwrite
>   some of the existing files there.

Source: http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.1.Final/userguide/pdf/resteasy-reference-guide-en-US.pdf

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Had the very same problem when trying to deploy a jax-rs (with resteasy) to glassfish 3.1.2.2. Tried to resolve what caused the inconsistency, took for hours and couldn't find it in the end - glassfish behavior became more and more strange.

My recommendation for everyone trying to run resteasy on gf: stop it and use jersey.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this issue as well and it took me forever to figure out how to resolve it.  Kevin Day was right.  The issue was that one of the dependencies in my POM indirectly pulled in Jackson and that dependency was placed in the POM file before the jaxrs dependency.  A fix was to simply move the jaxrs dependency to the top of the POM file so it gets picked up before Jackson.