# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.BuiltResponse.getHeaders()Ljavax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedMap

Tags: maven, resteasy

I am running into a dependency issue with resteasy.

I am trying to run a maven project using "jetty:run" command.  However I get this stack trace when I try to hit an endpoint for my REST component of the web application.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.BuiltResponse.getHeaders()Ljavax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedMap;
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.setDefaultContentType(ServerResponseWriter.java:195)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.writeNomapResponse(ServerResponseWriter.java:46)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:411)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:376)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:179)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220)
    at org.tynamo.resteasy.ResteasyRequestFilter.service(ResteasyRequestFilter.java:97)
    at $HttpServletRequestFilter_13b242ea59fdcfd6.service(Unknown Source)
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_13b242ea59fdcfd9.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.lazan.t5.atmosphere.services.internal.HttpServletHttpServletRequestFilter.service(HttpServletHttpServletRequestFilter.java:72)
    at org.lazan.t5.atmosphere.services.internal.AtmosphereHttpServletRequestFilter.service(AtmosphereHttpServletRequestFilter.java:50)
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_13b242ea59fdcfd9.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.got5.tapestry5.jquery.services.AjaxUploadServletRequestFilter.service(AjaxUploadServletRequestFilter.java:27)
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_13b242ea59fdcfd9.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.IgnoredPathsFilter.service(IgnoredPathsFilter.java:62)
    at $HttpServletRequestFilter_13b242ea59fdcfd2.service(Unknown Source)
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_13b242ea59fdcfd9.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$1.service(TapestryModule.java:852)
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_13b242ea59fdcfd9.service(Unknown Source)
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_13b242ea59fdcfd0.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.TapestryFilter.doFilter(TapestryFilter.java:171)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1148)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:387)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:417)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:535)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:865)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:539)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:520)
```

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618587/jetty-9-0-embedded-and-resteasy-3-0-keeps-throwing-nosuchmethoderror) but it did not solve my issue after putting the dependency at the top.  I also didn't have this dependency in my pom.xml file, so I guess I am depending on something that is using a bad dependency?

### EDIT 2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>graphene-parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>graphene</groupId>
        <version>4.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>graphene-rest</artifactId>
    <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
    <properties>
        <resteasy.version>3.0.1.Final</resteasy.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>graphene</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphene-model</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>graphene</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphene-dao</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>graphene</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphene-search</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>graphene</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphene-util</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Here we are enforcing a specific version of resteasy and it's modules. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency><!-- Tapestry integration with RESTEasy. -->
            <groupId>org.tynamo</groupId>
            <artifactId>tapestry-resteasy</artifactId>
            <version>0.3.2</version>
            <exclusions><!-- Here we exclude the built in resteasy versions, so we 
                    can specify our own versions. -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.tynamo</groupId>
            <artifactId>tapestry-model-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- end Testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>vande</groupId>
            <artifactId>vande</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- This changes the WAR file packaging so that what would normally go 
                into WEB-INF/classes is instead packaged as WEB-INF/lib/<appname>.jar. This 
                is necessary for Tapestry to be able to search for page and component classes 
                at startup. Only certain application servers require this configuration, 
                please see the documentation at the Tapestry 5 project page (http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry5/). -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archiveClasses>false</archiveClasses>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <description>Baseline rest services</description>
</project>
```

### EDIT 1

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
      <groupId>com.humangeo.graphene</groupId>
      <artifactId>humangeo-graphene-movies</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>humangeo-graphene-movies-web</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <description>Web module (war) for Movies demo</description>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${base.project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphene-rest</artifactId>
            <version>${base.project.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Here's the war overlay -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${base.project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphene-web</artifactId>
            <version>${base.project.version}</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Here's just the classes, needed for compilation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${base.project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphene-web</artifactId>
            <version>${base.project.version}</version>
            <classifier>classes</classifier>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${base.project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphene-model</artifactId>
            <version>${base.project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${base.project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphene-dao</artifactId>
            <version>${base.project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${base.project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphene-search</artifactId>
            <version>${base.project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${base.project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphene-util</artifactId>
            <version>${base.project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${base.project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphene-memorydb</artifactId>
            <version>${base.project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${base.project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphene-dao-sql</artifactId>
            <version>${base.project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${base.project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphene-dao-neo4j</artifactId>
            <version>${base.project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${base.project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphene-model</artifactId>
            <version>${base.project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${base.project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphene-dao</artifactId>
            <version>${base.project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${base.project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphene-export</artifactId>
            <version>${base.project.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <!-- This repository is only needed when the Tapestry version is a preview 
            release, rather than a final release. -->
        <repository>
            <id>apache-staging</id>
            <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/staging/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <finalName>humangeo-graphene-movies-web</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource><!-- This is for picking up any Tapestry .tml templates, .properties 
                    or other resources which are in the src directory. Optionally these could 
                    be in the corresponding resources directory but we don't enforce that on 
                    developers. -->
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.*</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/*.class</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/filtered-resources</directory>
                <targetPath>filtered</targetPath>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <workDirectory>target\overlay-war-folder</workDirectory>
                    <webXml>src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>

                    <overlays>
                        <overlay>
                            <groupId>${base.project.groupId}</groupId>
                            <artifactId>graphene-web</artifactId>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>**/log4j.properties</exclude>
                                <exclude>WEB-INF/lib/*.jar</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </overlay>
                    </overlays>
                    <!-- If true, this will package the classes as their own jar, INSIDE 
                        the war's web-inf/lib. At the moment this seems incompatible with the attachClasses 
                        flag, which we absolutely need for building. -->
                    <archiveClasses>false</archiveClasses>
                    <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
                    <!-- Just to be explicit. 'classes' is the default. This makes a second 
                        target as a jar with just the classes and no html/js -->
                    <classesClassifier>classes</classesClassifier>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Run the application using "mvn jetty:run" -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: can you share your pom.xml?

Comment: that pom doesn't show your resteasy dependencies.. are they placed in graphene-rest project?

Comment: We're you able to figure this out?  I'm experiencing the same problem using resteasy 3.0.10.  We recently upgraded to Jetty 9, which also required me to update javax.servlet-api to 3.X (I went with 3.1.0).

Comment: @MattTraynham, I was not able to fix the issue.

Comment: @bdparrish, I think I was able to.  I was using Swagger 1.3, which was additionally adding the jsr311 dependency.  It caused a duplicate of the javax.ws.rs.core.Response class which BuiltResponse extends.  The jsr311 dependency doesn't have the `getHeaders` method.  Maybe you have a duplicate javax.ws.rs.core.Response class, from a different package.

If you're using Maven, you can use `mvn dependency:tree` to check all dependent packages, and optionally use `<exclude>` in the pom files.

Comment: This answer worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19708873/1685098